Setup a Zustand readonly store
We are using for our frontend application store Zunstand with Immer for immutability and Zustand lens for separating slices.
I noticed that, due to an error runtime in Javascript console, we used a sort function (which mutates arrays), causing the application to crash because Immer prohibits mutating the store.
For now we replaced the usage of sort with toSorted, resolving the issue since toSorted is a non-mutating method. Nevertheless, we'd like TypeScript to assist us with this in the future.
How can we ensure that the store's type is readonly? I attempted to make all lenses ReadonlyDeep (using the type-fest utility), but that seems to result in a cascade of TypeScript issues.
